# Using Recessed Lighting with a 6 pin connector instead of a 4 pin?

Tags: electrical, recessed-lighting, connectors

I just purchased some recessed housings (Halo H7ICAT) and they already came with Wago 773-104 connectors. As you see below

[image]

1 pin is used for the light.

1 pin is for the actual power.

and 2 are open to other recessed lights.

But for 1 of the recessed housing, I need 1 more connection to avoid drilling through 6 ceiling studs.

Would there be any problem with replacing the 4-pin snap in connector with a 6-pin (773-106) connector?

My breaker is a 20 amp, and im running 12/2 electrical wiring over a dimmer switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Just pigtail off to another 773-104

I would simply get another Wago 773-104 or equivalent connector and use a short length of 12AWG wire to pigtail the connector on your recessed lights to the new connector.  Repeat this for the neutral and ground, and you should be good to go!

As an aside -- one could pull the wire out of the connector, but it tends to nick the wire up, in addition to rendering the connector useless.

Comment: I also was thinking about doing the same thing.